# Filter nested objects in elasticsearch query based on query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have doc with multiple nested documents. The nested queries work fine but they would still return all the nested objects (i.e. the whole document) even though search query would only match a few nested objects. It does however filter the documents as a whole.

Here is an example:

```
PUT /demo
{
  "mappings": {
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "employees": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT
/demo/company/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Google",
  "emp_count": 3,
  "employees": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "address": {
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "state": "California",
      "country": "United States"
    }
  }]
}

PUT
/demo/company/2
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Facebook",
  "emp_count": 3,
  "employees": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Amber",
    "address": {
      "city": "Bangalore",
      "state": "Karnataka",
      "country": "India"
    }
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adrian",
    "address": {
      "city": "Palo Alto",
      "state": "California",
      "country": "United States"
    }
  }]
}

PUT
/demo/company/3
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Microsoft",
  "emp_count": 3,
  "employees": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Aman",
    "address": {
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "New York",
      "country": "United States"
    }
  }]
}
```

When searching for `India` in the address, I should ideally only get `Facebook` with one nested object, but I get all the nested objects. How can I filter the nested objects returned?

Example query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score":{
      "query":{
        "nested":{
         "path":"employees",
         "score_mode":"max",
         "query": {
            "multi_match":{
              "query":"India",
              "type":"cross_fields",
              "fields":[
                "employees.address.city",
                "employees.address.country",
                "employees.address.state"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output of this query is `Facebook` with all employees while I only want  `Amber`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner_hits` to obtain the desired result.Use the below query:

```
GET /demo/company/_search
{
"query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "employees",
        "query" : {
            "match" : {"employees.address.country" : "India"}
        },
        "inner_hits" : {} 
    }
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 1.4054651,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "demo",
        "_type": "company",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.4054651,
        "_source": {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Facebook",
           "emp_count": 3,
           "employees": [
              {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "Amber",
                 "address": {
                    "city": "Bangalore",
                    "state": "Karnataka",
                    "country": "India"
                 }
              },
              {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "Adrian",
                 "address": {
                    "city": "Palo Alto",
                    "state": "California",
                    "country": "United States"
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
           "employees": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 1,
                 "max_score": 1.4054651,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "demo",
                       "_type": "company",
                       "_id": "2",
                       "_nested": {
                          "field": "employees",
                          "offset": 0
                       },
                       "_score": 1.4054651,
                       "_source": {
                          "id": 1,
                          "name": "Amber",
                          "address": {
                             "city": "Bangalore",
                             "state": "Karnataka",
                             "country": "India"
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     }
    ]
  }
```

You can see, `inner_hits` section has only those employees which match the criteria. 
But `inner_hits` was introduced in elasticsearch 1.5.0. So version should be greater than elasticsearch 1.5.0. You can refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-inner-hits.html) for more information.

Comment: I can but the problem with `inner_hits` is that I can't (or at least haven't been able to figure out how) to let sort only pick up matching nested_objects. If I change the `emloyees.address.country` to `United States` and apply sorting on `employees.address.state`, `Facebook`'s `state` will appear to be "Karnataka" despite that results not being present in inner_hits.